# Has the allowed request rate (rate-limit) been changed?

Tags: support, rate-limiting

Over the last few days, I've often been rate-limited:

> Too many requests
>
> This IP address (x.x.x.x) has performed an unusual high number of
> requests and has been temporarily rate limited...
>
> Method: rate limit
>
> Reason: Request rate.

**True**

- I run [bots](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6294609/queen) which query the SE-API every minute and feed information to multiple chat rooms
- I participate with my account in multiple chat rooms
- I visit questions and answers at a fairly high rate (normally just to flag as NAA or some offensive comments).

***But***

I have been doing this for more then a year without any problems. I'm not aware of any recent change in what I'm doing which would cause me to be rate-limited more often.

That this is happening much more often over the last few days is why I'm asking if you've changed the rate-limit mechanism (more strict?, started including chat, SE-API?), or if it's only some temporary issue?

This information is important.  If it's a permanent change, I will need to modify what I do in order to avoid being rate-limited this often (e.g. change my query strategy towards the [SE-API](https://api.stackexchange.com/), limit the number of chat rooms I interact with, limit the number of rooms in which the bots report, etc.) .

Comment: I've also been experiencing this rate-limit lockout more often recently. At least for me, the lockout has restricted normal access to SE pages (i.e. the lockout page is displayed instead of questions), but has *not* affected SE API access. I've been able to use the SE API in other tabs throughout the lockouts. Lockouts have been for relatively short periods of time. I'd estimate at 10 minutes, or so, but I keep forgetting to measure the actual lockout period. For me, the lockout has usually happened when rapidly moving from one question to another using AJAX rather than loading new pages.

Comment: You don't have the "who ignored me" chat userscript installed do you? or any other userscripts that could be impacting this? That userscript recently (as of a few weeks ago) started getting a lot of us ratelimited over in js chat recently, so i think they did change something.

Comment: @Kevin No, I don't, I have a few user scripts (that I have been checking and testing to remove) anyway they are old stuff (installed several month/year ago), it seems in some way related to chat (not api), I have removed the duplicate reporting bots from some rooms (with less users) and since I seem to have less problems. I hope we get an answer, so I can notify RO's of those rooms that I can not run the bot in them anymore if this is the case.

Comment: Maybe you should consider running the bot query once every 5 minutes. It is possible that the amount of time it causes the server to process queries is also a factor.

Comment: @TravisJ I actually do not think the it has to do with api (hence how often I run query has no effect, it has it's own back-off time if to often). My guess is that it's a new chat request limit, the problem with the bot is that it's also in multiple chat rooms, listening to messages. However I'm only guessing, something however probably have changed [not only me with bots](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/111347?m=38116789#38116789) is experience this

Comment: Perhaps it is related to the maximum amount of sockets the bot is connecting to? You only need one socket connection in order to send to any chat room.

Comment: @TravisJ I think it's related to something that SO have changed (maybe after the [readonly issue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/298744/320339)), our [chat lib](https://github.com/Tunaki/chatexchange) is fairly optimized. Lets see if they answer or we just need to figure out how to avoid it.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

We moved chat to Fastly during the [failover](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/298671/brief-maintenances-planned-for-sat-july-22-2017-at-0001-utc-fri-july-21-8pm) to our Colorado datacenter earlier this month as it makes things easier not having to wait for DNS changes to propagate. Things looked like they were working as expected, but in the past few days we found there were some complications with chat behind Fastly. One of the issues was it caused a number of users to be rate limited when they re-opened Chrome with multiple chat tabs.

Earlier today we reverted the change so that chat is no longer behind Fastly, which should help prevent the recent rate limiting issues. We plan on moving chat back to Fastly at some point in the future, but we need to do more testing first to make sure it doesn't cause any unintended issues.

Comment: Thanks for the speedy answer, when it returns back to *Fastly*, will it effect the rate limit in someway for people using chat?, hence also chat activity will be included and it was not before?

Comment: @PetterFriberg not sure yet. Chat previously was not included in the rate limiting system, but we would like it to be included in the future so it prevents a potential DoS vector. But we would want to make sure it doesn't interfere with normal use, which it most definitely was for these past few weeks.